# Thread re-use solutions rather than using 'Executor'

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

How to **re-use threads**? Is there any better or alternative solution than using **'Executor'**?

Comment: No, `ExecutorService` is the **best**.

Comment: Even if you ever implement a better thread managing algorithm, it would be even better if that new solution implements the standard `ExecutorService` interface. And then you are again at the point that there’s no better solution than an `ExecutorService`. That happens if you mix up algorithms and interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, The better way is use thread pool. `ExecuterService` is one of the best way to have thread pool. Using thread pool you can rely on both performance and thread management else your system will get crack due to thread handling issues.

Comment: But still..I'm supposed to re-use threads without using 'executor'. Is there any solution?

Comment: @user3030298 You can do what ThreadPoolExecutor does.  This is not better, but possible.

Comment: @sree - if you implement your own solution of thread reusing, this would mean you reimplemented a thread pool. It may make sense if you have special requirements to the thread pool which are not covered by standard implementations.

Comment: Thnk u @AlexeiKaigorodov